# Testing Chef cookbook failure

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen, chefspec

I'm writing a cookbook with custom resource that (among other things) validates SSH keys through `ssh-keygen`. I need to test scenario in which user feeds in invalid input and resource should raise according exception, so i'm searching for a way to verify that 'given following input ... Chef run fails'.

If i understand everything correctly, Test Kitchen implies that every converge ends in success, and ChefSpec implies that resources are never really executed (so my ssh-keygen calls will never be invoked at all).

Are there any conventional ways to test such a case?

Comment: Yes, mocking the shellout call as any other library, as documented [here](https://github.com/chefspec/chefspec#ruby-libraries-file-fileutils-etc) on ChefSpec readme. And expect it to raise an exception, this should match the whole thing.

Comment: Should copy this down to an answer :)

Comment: @Tensibai the actual problem is not mocking, i guess i was too precise talking about cookbook internals. I need to test that my resource responds as expected on different responses from ssh-keygen, but ChefSpec is not executing my resource - as far as i understand, that's the intentionally only mode of ChefSpec. So in fact i can test that my resource was called somewhere, can test `only_if` / `not_if` guards, but not the resource behavior itself.

Comment: Is it a custom resource ?

Comment: @Tensibai yes, it is. I always forget to include the most important parts in the question.

Comment: Then you need to tell chefspec to [step_into](https://github.com/chefspec/chefspec#testing-lwrps) this custom resource

Comment: @Tensibai seems to be the solution. I can't try it right now, but hopefully will try it in a day or two.

Comment: @Tensibai worked like a charm, fell free to leave an answer - i'll accept it

Comment: Would you mind to edit the question first to include the hidden informations? It will be more useful to others (I'll see tomorrow to summarize the comment into an answer)

Comment: It's been almost 3 years since this question was asked, but I am still looking for an answer to the TestKitchen half of the question.  The ChefSpec half seems fairly straightforward, but nobody has addressed TestKitchen yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the inner bits of a custom_resource your have to tell ChefSpec to [step_into](https://github.com/chefspec/chefspec#testing-lwrps) it. You're right ChefSpec doesn't execute providers in normal case.

To get a proper test on a failure, you should `expect(:chef_run).to raise_error` as describe [here in the documentation](https://github.com/chefspec/chefspec#expecting-exceptions)

Quote of the documentation for `step_into`:

> In order to run the actions exposed by your LWRP, you have to
>   explicitly tell the `Runner` to step into it:
>
> require 'chefspec'
>
> ```
> describe 'foo::default' do
>   let(:chef_run) do
>     ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new(step_into: ['my_lwrp']).converge('foo::default')
>   end
>
>   it 'installs the foo package through my_lwrp' do
>     expect(chef_run).to install_package('foo')
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> NOTE: If your cookbook exposes LWRPs, it is highly recommended you
>   also create a libraries/matchers.rb file as outlined below in the
>   "Packaging Custom Matchers" section. **You should never step_into an
>   LWRP unless you are testing it. Never step_into an LWRP from another
>   cookbook!**